# Cannot install Google Plugin in Eclipse 4.4

Tags: eclipse, google-plugin-eclipse

I have Eclipse 4.4 on my Windows 7.  I got the following error when trying to install Google Plugin:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.
>    Software being installed: Google Plugin for
>   Eclipse 4.3 3.5.1.v201312301723-rel-r43
>   (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e43.feature.feature.group
>   3.5.1.v201312301723-rel-r43)
>    Missing requirement: Google Eclipse 4.2 Platform Plugin 3.5.1.v201312301723-rel-r43
>   (com.google.gdt.eclipse.platform.e42 3.5.1.v201312301723-rel-r43)
>   
> ***requires 'bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime [3.8.0,3.10.0)'***
>   but it could not be found
>    Cannot satisfy
>   dependency:
>       From: Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.3 3.5.1.v201312301723-rel-r43 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e43.feature.feature.group
>   3.5.1.v201312301723-rel-r43)
>       To: com.google.gdt.eclipse.platform.e42 [3.5.1.v201312301723-rel-r43]

Comment: i think your plugins need to be upgrade, or some feature from google plugin need to unselect before installation.

Comment: actually, your eclipse is latest , u can update google plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin has a hard requirement to Eclipse 3.8 (up to to 3.10, which doesn't exist), which means it's not able to install on Eclipse 4. See if there is an updated version of the plugin.

If not, you have to install Eclipse 3.8 to run the plugin. The other alternative is to see if the source is available and change the requirements so that it will be able to install on 4.4. But you will be taking a huge risk and using the software in an environment it wasn't designed or tested for.

Comment: It turn out that Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.3 only works with Eclipse Luna (4.4) M2 Build.  I had M3 Build on my machine.  Downgrade Eclipse Luna (4.4) M3 to M2 and reinstall Google 4.3.  It is working now.Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 12):

Posted on 27th June on https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-plugin-eclipse/4YACQROrB2U/2cAEuoW6fkQJ :

> Hey all,
>
> Sorry about the delay. I'm going to spend some time on this, and I'd
>   like to have this released within 2 weeks. I'll post updates to this
>   thread...
>
> Rajeev [Dayal]

and then on the 1st August... ( https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-plugin-eclipse/4YACQROrB2U/W80jj-cbZ5gJ )

> The official version of GPE 3.7.0 is live:
>
> https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.4  (luna)
>
> https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.3  (kepler)
>
> https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2 (juno)

Answer (score 1):

New Plugin available and working: https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-4.4

Answer (score 0):

I have found that it is possible to change the manifests for the plugin so that it installs in Luna.

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23119661/google-plugin-for-eclipse-luna), using instructions on a [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-plugin-eclipse/4YACQROrB2U/discussion), I have 'upgraded' my GDT plugin and installed it successfully in Luna. It seems to work fine.

As Alistair Collins points out in his answer, there are apparently incompatibilities with m2eclipse. I don't use that plugin, and I haven't noticed any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, while Google doesn't release an updated version of the plugin, Vinicio Ferreira put [this unofficial version of 4.3's plugin modified to work on 4.4](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-plugin-eclipse/4YACQROrB2U/W-nyKMckw4EJ) together in the Google Groups thread about this issue.

It did the trick for me, at least for now.

Here's also [a step by step guide on how to download and install it](http://www.vlogg.com/14805/un-official-google-eclipse-plugin-luna-4-4-now-available-download/).

Answer (score 0):

Added  http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases, http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna to the eclipse software sites and it worked for me :)

Comment: Why do you think, it is better than other answers?

Comment: I don't say its better. it just worked for me while the others didn't . :)

Answer (score -2):

Install the latest version of the Google plugin (-rel43) into Kepler. Then get Luna and manually copy all features and plugins with com.google.* from the kepler installation to the Luna installation. Just worked fine for me.

Comment: Could you tell the error you got? "Did not work for me" and down voting is not really a constructive feedback.