# Google adt/gwt support for eclipse 4.4 (Luna)

Tags: java, android, gwt, adt, google-plugin-eclipse

Have anyone gotten the release version of eclipse 4.4 to work with adt(Android development) and/or google web toolkit(gwt).

It seems like the gwt/adt plugins don't works with eclipse 4.4, so is there a secret place to download new versions or should I keep using 4.3 -(

Edit:
The reason I thought adt was not working was that the documentation(http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) says that the plugin is called "ADT Plugin" which it is not.

Comment: for adt it is working perfectly with luna , i started using it already , but for GWT , it is not working .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Plugin for Eclipse Luna?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23119661/google-plugin-for-eclipse-luna)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Google just released its official SDK for Eclipse Luna: https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/getting_started

Answer (score 8):

For adt ,

> help -> Install new Software ->
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ -> don't select everything

(it worked that way for me) i selected everything except Native development tools(i guess you don't need them if you debelop in java)  and it's working well for me .

Comment: Thanks. Seems to be working, after an extra restart of eclipse. Do you know if there is a way to get gwt to work too?

Comment: i managed to install the others in the same way , but the plugin is not working (don't forget to accpet the answer if you think it's right)

Answer (score 3):

well… the gwt plugin actually can not work with luna release since it has a bundle dependency for eclipse core.runtime [3.8.0,3.10.0), here, ")" means it NOT includes 3.10.0 wihich is used in luna, however, it can been get rid of by modifying the  osgi bundle file and then  it will works fine with luna ,at least for me for now.

1 download the last update site zip file from google eclipse plugin site
2 unpack it
3 then you will need to modify 2 files firstly

an osgi META INF/manifest file included in a jar named *gdt*e42 (sorry, forget the full name, you can find it when you are trying to install the plugin, luna will complain that some dep bundle is missed)that is located in plugins dir, just change core.runtime version from 3.10.0) to 3.10.0]

another one should be contents.jar (maybe artifacts. jar), same above

now you can install the plugin if you have already have the eclipse RCP installed

however, install will failed because the md5 hashing is changed,

finally, copy the expected md5 from error message dialog to replace the old md5 value in artifacts.jar(maybe contents.jar)

now reinstall the plugin ,it should work for now

---

UPDATED:

maybe you should remove the bundle-version from MANIFEST.MF at com.google.gdt.eclipse.platform.e42 jar
and change the version to "0.0.0" from content.xml at content.jar

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `Help----->Install New Software` option, you might encounter this error message just like i did trying to install the Android plugin.

```
An error occurred during the org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust phase.
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust, operand=, action=).
Error reading signed content.
error in opening zip file
```

My solution was to go through `Help-->Eclipse Marketplace` and then search for `"Android"` Select the plugin from the search result and install it from there.