# Android SDK with Eclipse Luna

Tags: android, eclipse

I got a new computer, I would like to install Eclipse Luna for my android applications? Do you think it is good to install the Luna version or go with eclipse Kepler?

On my old computer I used to have eclipse Kepler? What do you recommend?

Thanks!

Comment: From [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24431005/google-adt-gwt-support-for-eclipse-4-4-luna), it seems that there is no problem for Eclipse Luna with ADT (Android SDK). However, if you're working with GWT, please check that question.

Comment: I don't use GWT... I use only ADT.. so I guess I will just download Luna. install..Thanks!