# Which Eclipse works flawlessly with ADT?

Tags: java, eclipse, adt

There are many Eclipse versions out there. e.g.:Indigo,Juno,Kepler,Luna,Mars. Which of these works best with ADT? There are many such questions on Stack Overflow, but they are all 4-5 years old. I am looking for something more recent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which of these works best with ADT?

That would depend on what version of ADT you are using. To know more about which versions of Eclipse supports what all ADT version refer to [ADT Plugin Release Notes](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html).

I don't think there is any "best" eclipse version to work with an ADT. Just go for the latest Eclipse version that can use the ADT version you intent to use.

Also as per the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)

Note: If you have been using Eclipse with ADT, be aware that [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html) is now the official IDE for Android, so you should migrate to Android Studio to receive all the latest IDE updates. For help moving projects, see [Migrating to Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html).

Answer (score 5):

I reached your question as I was wondering about this myself, since I found "the official IDE for Android" (Android Studio 1.1.0 Build 135.1740770) pretty horrible:

- It doesn't work well with [multi-module imported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29877422/4807784) projects.
- Its Logcat output format is several years backwards compared with that of Eclipse

What I do know is that back then, when Google still supported Eclipse as "official", it released a nice integrated **bundle** (`adt-bundle-windows-x86_64.zip`) that was based on **Juno** (
Eclipse Classic 4.2.2). It worked very well with  ADT v21 and SDK Tools v21 (note: ADT and SDK are totally different things, their version numbers don't have to necessarily be identical).

Right now (as of 2015-05-01), you can download [ADT 23.0.6 (March 2015)](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#) which is designed to work with [SDK Tools r24.1.2](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html).

Right now (as of 2015-05-01), you can also download Eclipse Kepler (4.3.2) and Luna (4.4.2). It is very tempting to always use the latest & greatest but I vaguely recall problems with it[?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24431005/4807784). The [Google Plugins](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/getting_started) for Luna & Kepler are really for web applications, not for Android.

So in the meanwhile (until Android Studio catches up with the maturity and the features the Eclipse+ADT has), I am going to stick with [the final version of the ADT Bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27449206/4807784). It is still using **Juno** (
Eclipse Classic 4.2.2), so I guess this is the most stable/reliable Eclipse+ADT combo.

If you have additional information on seamless & flawless development for Android with an Eclipse version higher than Juno, I would love to learn more about it.

Answer (score 2):

In my test with Linux Mint 17, ADT 23.0.7 works best with Eclipse Luna (4.4). The Android layout editor has various graphical glitches in Eclipse Mars (4.5), for example most of GUI widgets palette do not show up until you hover your mouse cursor and you get error-report popup constantly in bottom-right of the screen.

EDIT:
Google has [deleted](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adt.html) the download link of ADT, so ADT 23.0.7 is now officially the final version. Therefore, I can conclude that the **last supported Eclipse version is Luna (4.4)**.

In the case you want to download the final ADT, the link is below:
https://dl.google.com/android/ADT-23.0.7.zip

Refer to the "Troubleshooting ADT Installation" section of [Installing the Eclipse Plugin](https://web.archive.org/web/20150905084220/https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) (Web Archived) for instructions. Note that you have to select ADT-23.0.7.zip instead of ADT-23.0.6.zip.

Comment: This is very useful advice.  Mars is unusable for Android development (Android plugin 23.0) using Ubuntu.  The screen layout wysiwyg tool is very glitchy.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, i think you should have to use Android Studio, Android studio is official IDE for android.

if you want to go with eclipse, i have good experience with helios, but it depends which version of ADT you are using.

Comment: Any updates for Neon? I am going to install right now