# From Eclipse to Android Studio: Why is proguard.cfg used when NOT building Release?

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, proguard

So, I have been trying to migrate the development of a multi-project (eclipse projects that is) app to Android Studio (v1.1).

Importing via File > Import Project was really easy and went without incident.

However, when I tried Make/Rebuild project I encountered numerous surprises. The first, not Proguard-related, had to do with source file encoding (originally in Windows-1252), but I quickly found a solution using this [Windows-1252 > Reload > UTF-8 > Convert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24568901/4807784) answer.

Then, "error: cannot find symbol class" for a `com.comp.mod.X` class of mine. I then solved it by going to the module (Android Studio module that is, previously an Eclipse project) that contains that class and added to its **proguard.cfg** the following:

```
-keep public class com.comp.mod.X
```

Which left me with an "error: cannot find symbol variable" for a const BB defined in the aforementioned class. I solved this by adding to the same **proguard.cfg** the following:

```
-keepclassmembers class com.comp.mod.X {
    public static final boolean BB;
}
```

That left me with only one "error: cannot find symbol method getPreferenceX()". I solve this by adding to the same **-keepclassmembers** that method, so that the above now looks:

```
-keepclassmembers class com.comp.mod.X {
    public static final boolean BB;
    public static java.lang.String getPreferenceX();
}
```

I thought I was done, but to my dismay, when I attempted to rebuild the project, I received numerous additional errors from other modules in the project, all of the type to "error: cannot find symbol class/variable/method" and related to some **proguard.cfg**.

I could have continued butchering the proguard.cfg files for each and every module but at this point I am beginning to suspect that I am doing something fundamentally wrong, because those proguard.cfg files work perfectly under Eclipse. So,

1. Why all of a sudden these are no longer good for Android Studio?
2. If [ProGuard runs only when you build your application in **release** mode](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html), why is the Android Studio based build complaining about "cannot find symbol" due to Proguard's obfuscation?

What am I missing?

**Note:** I have **not** attempted "Generate Signed APK". All I do is "Rebuild Project".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently (as of 2015-04-24), `minifyEnabled`'s default value of `false` for all build types is incorrect for **multi-module** projects, in which some modules (app included) are *dependent* on other modules. This is due to [bug #52962](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=52962) that causes build types to **not** propagate to libraries -- they are always built as RELEASE.

Suggestions to work around this bug or notifications of its fix are most welcome.