# What is the default for minifyEnabled for buildType not explicitly scripted?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, proguard, minify

I imported several eclipse projects to Android Studio (v1.1).

In the original Eclipse environment, they use Proguard for release mode.

In the Android Studio environment, this was translated to the following in the `build.gradle` script (by the import, not by me):

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles 'proguard.cfg'
    }
}
```

I understand that this means that *"in `release` build, enable Proguard's minify, using proguard.cfg"*.

The problem, however, is that minify seems to be happening in non-release build (i.e. debug) as well!

How is this possible?

What is the default for minifyEnabled for debug build?

---

**UPDATE 1:** Thanks to the answer below, I now know that the default is `false`. Which means something else is building the various modules minified in debug build.

I am posting the **entire** build.gradle for one of the modules that get minified in debug build:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 8
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 8
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles 'proguard.cfg'
        }
    }
}
```

The entire `build.gradle` for the project itself (i.e. top level) is:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

I cannot spot here anything that could explain enforcing minify on a debug build.

---

**UPDATE 2:** Suspecting a mismatch between app's build (`debug`) and the modules on which it depends (`release`?), I also checked the [Build Variant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27278352) view on the the left panel. The all show `debug` unequivocally.

---

**UPDATE 3:** It appears that I hit [a bug/limitation in Android-Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27277864/4807784)?

I truly need all modules built in `debug` mode when the app is built in `debug` mode.

Any ideas how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The default value for `minifyEnabled` is `false` for all build types, as @laalto answered.

However, currently (as of 2015-04-24), this is not true for **multi-module** projects, in which some modules (app included) are *dependent* on other modules. This is due to [bug #52962](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=52962) that causes build types to **not** propagate to libraries -- they're always built as RELEASE.

Suggestions to work around this bug or notifications of its fix are most welcome.

Answer (score 16):

> What is the default for minifyEnabled for debug build?

The default value for `minifyEnabled` is `false` for all build types. [Reference](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Types).

> The problem, however, is that minify seems to be happening in non-release build (i.e. debug) as well!
>
> How is this possible?

Your debug build gets proguard treatment possibly by some other definition somewhere, or an external build script you're using.

---

In your updated question, you have a library project and an app project that uses a minified library even for debug builds. That's a "feature". For a solution, consider the following also mentioned in the [issue report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=52962#c35):

Build all variants of the library project by adding the following to its `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    publishNonDefault true
}
```

In the app project, choose the build type specific dependency with

```
dependencies {
    releaseCompile project(path: ':theotherproject', configuration: 'release')
    debugCompile project(path: ':theotherproject', configuration: 'debug')
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought that the default would be `false` but the fact that [something is minifying my non-release build](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29761457/4807784) is a mystery to me. How do I find what is responsible for minifying my debug build? I am new to Android Studio and Gradle and at this point I am groping in the dark. Any tips on that? +1 for now, will accept once I have better insight into what's going on.

Comment: I just posted an update, in case this could provide additional insight. I am still groping in the dark. Thanks.

Comment: Yup. A bug in Android's Gradle plugin:  https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=52962