# Is there a Gradle plugin for Eclipse Luna?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, gradle, eclipse-luna

I'm trying to integrate `Eclipse Luna` with `Gradle`.

[**Eclipse Integration Gradle**](https://github.com/spring-projects/eclipse-integration-gradle/#eclipse-integration-gradle) GitHub page includes instructions for [**Installing Gradle Tooling from update site**](https://github.com/spring-projects/eclipse-integration-gradle/#installing-gradle-tooling-from-update-site).

I followed the instructions for the release (stable) version.

After I selected all the components (as shown below) I proceeded with installation.

[image]

It didn't go as expected and brought me to the **Install Remediation Page** (below) that showed that only **Gradle IDE** component could be installed. ( [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1cDd.jpg) for larger image).
[image]

At this point I'm not sure what caused the problem and what to do about.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The plugin you are using is wrong. There is an update for Luna [here](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gradle-integration-eclipse-44#.VB_gPGOMl40).

You can alternatively install the plugin directly within eclipse with [this integration link](http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.4/).

Comment: What is Spring Ide or Spring framework, is it necessary if i want only install gradle  support plug-in

Comment: @Mokhtarabadi: have a look at https://github.com/spring-projects/eclipse-integration-gradle/#eclipse-integration-gradle

Comment: http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.4/ has access denied. is there a way to add gradle to an existing eclipse project without having to use their special ide?

Comment: as you see  in the site http://spring.io/tools/ggts/all they must have internal server error. Just wait for them to fix it.

Comment: @Water: Please use the other one, meanwhile I will try to find an alternative.

Answer (score 8):

Gradleware now offers direct support for the Eclipse IDE. See http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGradle/article.html for an introduction.

Comment: It seems to be slated for Eclipse 4.5 (Mars).

Comment: Should also work with older versions, if not please open a bug for Buildship project.

Comment: I was hoping the tutorial could take me far enough to do the "Hello World" projects at http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/writing-build-scripts-with-gradle/240168648?pgno=1 . Pasting them into build.gradle didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to plugin memtioned by @Campiador. You must have supported project nature in your eclipse's **.project** file in order for your project to show up in "Gradle Tasks" view.

See following example:

Add one or more natures in **build.gradle** file:

```
eclipse.project {
  natures 'org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.nature', 'org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature'
}
```

After this change, just run **gradle eclipse** command from your shell/command prompt. Newly generated **.project** will have proper natures in it. Just refresh your project in eclipse and now you will see your project in **Gradle Tasks** view.