# How to import library which has gradle dependencies

Tags: android, gradle

I have been trying to use tooltip in android app

referring https://github.com/nhaarman/supertooltips.

But I cant make the project run since it requires gradle dependency.

As soon as I import the project and try to run it it shows error.

How to compile it so that I can use it in my project

Comment: are you using eclipse?

Comment: You should post the error.

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.ryanharter.android.tooltips.sample/com.ryanharter.android.tooltips.sample.MyActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.ryanharter.android.tooltips.sample.MyActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ryanharter.android.tooltips.sample-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.ryanharter.android.tooltips.sample-1, /system/lib]]

Answer (score 0):

OK. Since you are using eclipse, you need to install Gradle plugin. There is an old nice tutorial [here](http://estiloasertivo.blogspot.com/2013/03/tutorial-howto-install-and-configure.html).

[Here](https://github.com/spring-projects/eclipse-integration-gradle/#eclipse-integration-gradle)'s the official spring guide and source code to Gradle plugin.

But particularly, if you are using eclipse Luna, you might want to review [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333657/is-there-a-gradle-plugin-for-eclipse-luna).