# can't install gradle integration for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gradle, eclipse-marketplace

my eclipse version is 4.4 luna and I can't install gradle integration for it.  I excluded dashboard and UAA components but nevertheless can't install and get the following message: 
the following solutions are not available: Gradle Integration for Eclipce(4.4) and then the following exception:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No artifact repository available.
noArtifactRepositoriesAvailable
```

Comment: What's the process you're following? Where are you downloading the plugin from?

Comment: The integration link provided in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333657/is-there-a-gradle-plugin-for-eclipse-luna) worked for me.